# why my app work perfect in debug mode and crash in release mode?

Tags: react-native

hey there i am new with react native i created an app everything works perfect when i debug it but when i build it it crash in a screen and give me this errors

2019-07-05 12:29:53.403 21905-21925/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
    Process: com.foo, PID: 21905
    com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Requiring unknown module "./locale/fr"., stack:
    h@2:1448
    d@2:868
    Dt@714:16712
    Tt@714:17738
    Yt@714:16801
    n@713:2042
    Sn@90:30120
    Or@90:45887
    na@90:72881
    ra@90:73371
    Oa@90:80972
    Wa@90:80310
    Ue@90:83367
    De@90:13673
    We@90:13846
    receiveTouches@90:14605
    value@28:3311
    @28:822
    value@28:2565
    value@28:794
    value@-1

```
    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.showOrThrowError(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:54)
    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportFatalException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:38)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:158)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:232)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

here is my code there two places when i am working with moment here the first one :

```
import 'moment/locale/fr';
import moment from 'moment';

this.state = { 
      date: moment().locale('fr').format('dddd HH:mm');
}
and set the state to a Text
```

the second one is this class

```
import 'moment/locale/fr';
import moment from 'moment';

componentDidMount() {
   console.log(this.props.hours[0].openAt); 
   const date = new Date();
   const day = date.getDay();
   moment.locale('fr');
   for (let i = 0; i < this.props.hours.length; i++) {
       if (this.props.hours[i].day === day) {
           const format = 'hh:mm';
           const time = moment(date, format);
           const beforeTime = moment(this.props.hours[i].openAt, format);
            const afterTime = moment(this.props.hours[i].closeAt, format);

           if (time.isBetween(beforeTime, afterTime)) {
             this.setState({
                 ouvert: true
             });
           } else {
               this.setState({
                   ouvert: false
               });
           }
       }
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

Solved it like this: (In my case i have english and italian localization to enable)

Imported my local localization files as:

```
import * as en from "./locale/en.json";
import * as it from "./locale/it.json";
```

> Integrated moment localization

```
var moment = require("moment");
var itLocale = require("moment/locale/it");
var enLocale = require("moment/locale/en-gb");

moment.locale("en", enLocale);
moment.locale("it", itLocale);
```

Now works on debug/release mode.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this issue too and fixed it by downgrading the version of `moment` to `2.18.1`.

If you're using `moment-timezone` then you would need to add the following in your `package.json`

```
"resolutions": {
    "moment-timezone/moment": "2.18.1"
  },
```

Reference: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/4216

Answer (score 1):

Got this error when upgrading from React Native 0.60 to 0.63 and using the latest version of Moment.js (2.29.4).
Moment.js worked fine in all components except for the utils file (.fromNow() method particularly)

The error was caused by using `moment.locale('fr', {})` for extending the French locale instead of `moment.updateLocale('fr', {})`.

After switching to `updateLocale`, the issue was resolved.